What would be a good way of smoothing live/real time data or recognizing trends within live data consistently?
I receive live data stream ( ask and bid data ) from a particular data source, I then proceed to save this data in the TimescaleDB and later on process it for both live and historical testing ( forward-testing, backtesting and production ) ( I don't do high frequency trading, only a couple of trades ( ~10 ) per day ). So, after some experiments on historical data I found out that results of my backtesting ( and later on forwardtesting, which are almost identical ) essentially depend on how good I smooth my data/recognize the trends within data.
Of course, in an offline setting ( during backtesting and experimenting ) I can apply various non-causal filters/smoothers and this would work perfectly since filter/smoother has information about future data however in an online setting ( during forwardtesting and production ) these filters/smoothers lag and create the effect from the following image:

I then utilized different filters and methods in all stages of testing aside from production like the following:

Moving Average ( and different types of moving averages like least square, hull etc... )
Savitzky-Golay method
Whittaker-Eilers method
Heat equation method
Perona-Malik PDE
Kalman filter
1 euro filter
Low pass filter

And all perform poorly in an online setting since they all create this lag effect. I found some luck with utilizing estimation of least square moving average but that method creates too much over and undershoots in an trend so I assume I will have to combine it with some other specific method ( I don't have knowledge nor experience for something like that but I am still open to that idea ). So, essentially, after some time I realized that these filters and methods are not really an solution in fully causal setting since they create this lag and this essentially creates late signals in my algorithm.
I haven't tried the following, but I've got an idea of utilizing incremental curve fitting however the problem is that I need my curve to be consistent with historical data points while being open to introducing new data points and for this I haven't found an solution.

Another idea is using segmented linear regression to estimate trends but I haven't explored this idea fully.

I am happy to hear different experiences and answers related to this specific issue because I am almost sure that someone had to deal with this while creating trend-following algorithm. And keep in mind that I am new to this and signal processing as well, so be as detailed if you will and it would be great if you had a specific paper related to this, it would be of great help and greatly appreciated!

Define a two-dimensional function $f(t,\tau)$ where $t$ is the true time of your data stream and $\tau$ is an artificial “smoothing-time” dimension. Let $x(t)$ be the raw signal (bid/ask data). Impose the boundary condition
$$
f(t,0) = x(t) \quad \text{for all real } t.
$$
We now evolve $f$ along $\tau$ via the hyperbolic partial differential equation
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t \partial \tau} = \alpha \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t^2},
$$
where $\alpha > 0$ is a tunable parameter that controls how strongly the smoothing acts on the second temporal derivative. Observe that this PDE is hyperbolic in $(t,\tau)$, distinguishing it from the more common parabolic or elliptic filters (like the heat equation or Perona–Malik), which typically induce lag. The hyperbolic form helps preserve sharp transitions without incurring as much delay.
For small $\Delta \tau$, an explicit discretization can be done in real time. Let the time axis be discretized into points $t_n = t_0 + n \Delta t$, and let the smoothing axis be discretized by $\tau_m = m \Delta \tau$. Denote $f^m_n = f(t_n,\tau_m)$. Impose
$$
f^0_n = x(t_n) \quad \text{for all } n, \quad \text{and} \quad f^m_{n} = f^{m-1}_n \quad \text{when } n < 0 \text{ or } n > N_{\text{max}},
$$
to ensure data remains causal and well-defined. Then approximate
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t \partial \tau} \approx \frac{f^m_{n+1} - f^m_{n-1} - f^{m-1}_{n+1} + f^{m-1}_{n-1}}{4 \Delta t \Delta \tau},
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t^2} \approx \frac{f^m_{n+1} - 2 f^m_{n} + f^m_{n-1}}{(\Delta t)^2}.
$$
Plug these into the PDE to get
$$
\frac{f^m_{n+1} - f^m_{n-1} - f^{m-1}_{n+1} + f^{m-1}_{n-1}}{4 \Delta t \Delta \tau} = \alpha \frac{f^m_{n+1} - 2 f^m_{n} + f^m_{n-1}}{(\Delta t)^2}.
$$
Rearrange for $f^m_{n+1}$ in terms of known values. Increment $\tau$ in small steps, applying the update at each arrival of a new data point in real time. Stopping at some small $\tau = \tau_{\max}$ yields a smoothed function $f(t,\tau_{\max})$ that can be used as your trend estimate. This “hyperbolic” strategy does not rely on any future data (it is strictly causal) and, due to its wave-like propagation in $\tau$, tends to reduce lag while smoothing out short-scale fluctuations. Furthermore, one can tune $\alpha$ and $\tau_{\max}$ to adjust how aggressively the filter responds to new data while respecting the historical trend. Because the PDE is hyperbolic, shocks or edges in the data can propagate at finite speed in $\tau$, lessening the time delay often seen in classical causal filters.
By adjusting initial conditions, boundary conditions at the edges of your time window, or by introducing spatially varying $\alpha = \alpha(t)$ to adapt to evolving volatility, you can refine this method for a variety of trend-following tasks.
